# Solr Slow on Kubernetes - Possible Solution

Tags: performance, kubernetes, solr

I am writing this question to share the solution we found in our company.
We migrated Solr over a docker only solution to a kubernetes solution.

On kubernetes the environment ended up with slowness.
At least for me the solution was atypical.

**Environment:**

- solr(8.2.0) with just one node
- solr database with 250GB on disk
- kubernetes over Rancher
- Node with 24vcpus and 32GB of Ram
- Node hosts Solr and nginx ingress
- Reserved 30GB for the Solr pod in kubernetes
- Reserved 25GB for the Solr

**Expected Load:**

- 350 updates/min (pdf documents and html documents)
- 50 selects/min

The result was Solr degrading over time having high loads on host. The culpirit was heavy disk access.

Answer (score 1):

After one week of frustrated adjustments this is the simple solution we found:

Solr JVM had 25 GB. We decreased the value to 10GB.

This is the command to start solr with the new values:

/opt/solr/bin/solr start -f -force -a '-Xms10g -Xmx10g' -p 8983

If someone can explain what happened that would be great.
My guess is that solr was trying to make cash and kubernetes was reapping this cache. So Solr ended up in a continuous reading of the disk trying to build its cache.

Comment: You generally should not set `Xms` or `Xmx` with modern java on k8s. Modern java will automatically detect available k8s resources and auto-allocate a percentage of available memory to heap if `Xms` and `Xmx` are not set. You will want to ensure requests and limits are properly configured on the pod.